# Detecting corrupted PDFs in file uploads on heroku

Tags: python, pdf, heroku

At my company, we accept user-uploaded PDFs. A surprisingly high percent of these uploads are corrupted. Is there a way we could detect this reliably?

The app runs on python / heroku. A call to the CLI would be fine, and I've heard the `acroread` CLI tool by Adobe can be used to detect corrupted PDFs. However, it is not available in Heroku by default, and I don't see a debian package for it. Is there a straight-forward way to get this running on Heroku? Or is there an alternative (python package or CLI tool) that can achieve this?

Comment: There's a module called `pypdf` which offers an API to handle PDFs.  We are using this decently (but our PDFs are not corrupted).  But maybe you could use it to detect corruptions?

Comment: Any idea how it compares to `pdfminer`? My uncertainty about both is that I'm not sure how accurately they detect corruptions (not so worried about false negatives so much as false positives - that is, documents the library thinks are corrupt that actually are not.)

Comment: Sorry, I've got no experience with `pdfminer`.